# How to break from infinite generator loops from interactive shell in python

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I was learning `itertools` in Python and accidentally invoked an infinite loop in iPython shell, here's what my inputs:

```py
import itertools as it
list(it.zip_longest(it.count(), [1,2]))
```

The last line would run indefinitely until the computer crashes.

I tried to terminate the execution with `Ctrl-C`, but it didn't work.

How do I force the execution to terminate in this case?

Comment: Simply find the process id for the shell, and kill it, or close the terminal. There could be several ways for this.

Comment: @acpmasquerade at some point after running the code, the GUI became irresponsive and I had to force quit the app where iPython was run (a terminal emulator / editor / IDE).

Answer (score 2):

Python is a `interpreted` language hence it checks for instruction after each line. The same happens with `Ctrl-C` too.

`Ctrl-C` sends `KeyboardInterrupt` to Python interpreter and it is checked after each Python instruction but the output generation by `it.zip_longest(it.count(), [1,2])` is handled in C Code and the interrupt is handled afterwards but interpreter never checks for next instruction hence even on `Ctrl-C` the execution doesn't stop.